# how to stretch flexbox on full screen?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

how to make my flexbox stretched on fullscreen?
this is my website and I want to remove free space from it >>
[image]

please help me and tell me how to make my website fullscreen?
I tried to make margin and padding zero but not working :/

this is my website and please help me, this is very veri important. !important :)
lumin.ge/html/wwwabc

Comment: Can you post your current HTML and CSS code?

Comment: Yeah. We need to see the code to be able to help!

Comment: What a descriptive post! The amount you informed us of your problem will certainly make it easy to assist you. _Very_ easy.

Answer (score 4):

Edit -

The divs you wanted to stretch aren't even flex yet, here is a possible solution. **NOTE** You will have to play with it with smaller sizes, but it should be easy enough.

Add the following to your CSS.

```
.site-info {
  background: #F57828;
  text-align: center;
  height: 25vh;
}
#section2 .header {
  background: #000;
  height: 50vh;
}
```

Please post some code to help us help you. [This post](https://css-tricks.com/boxes-fill-height-dont-squish/) should help you get started though.

Example code from post -

```css
.fill-height-or-more {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.fill-height-or-more > div {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.some-area > div {
  padding: 1rem;
}
.some-area > div:nth-child(1) {
  background: #88cc66;
}
.some-area > div:nth-child(2) {
  background: #79b5d2;
}
.some-area > div:nth-child(3) {
  background: #8cbfd9;
}
.some-area > div:nth-child(4) {
  background: #9fcadf;
}
.some-area > div:nth-child(5) {
  background: #b3d4e6;
}
.some-area > div h1, .some-area > div h2 {
  margin: 0 0 0.2rem 0;
}
.some-area > div p {
  margin: 0;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="some-area fill-height-or-more">
  <div>
      <h1>Boxes That Fill Height (or more)</h1>
      <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
  </div>
  <div>
      <h2>Two</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Error ut.</p>
  </div>
  <div>
      <h2>Three</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Error ut.</p>
  </div>
  <div>
      <h2>Four</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Error ut.</p>
  </div>
  <div>
      <h2>Five</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Error ut.</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: The article / example allows you to stretch div's height using flex, which is what the author asked for.

Comment: Please post a repository or a jsfiddle so we can help you.